# With Lua, what's the easiest way to start writing code?

Tags: lua

I have a windows vista machine and also a mac with xcode. What would be the easiest way to start writing some Lua code?

Answer (score 1):

Download lua from [here](http://lua.org/). Compile it. Open up a text editor and start writing.

If you just want to try out some simple things, then try the online [lua demo](http://www.lua.org/demo.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just download - http://www.lua.org/download.html \
then:

Lua [hello world](http://icculus.org/~theoddone33/lua/)